# Prevent console logging from external package .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, logging

We're using an external package (Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data) which is clogging up the console with tons of logs. We are using console logging provider and stores everything that's written to console. The package doesn't seem to use a logger, it's probably more directly writing to console with Console.WriteLine or similar, so changing log level doesn't help.

Is there a way to prevent a specific package to output to console?

Here's a screenshot from the logging in vs code,the two upper logs (starting with P.*) are from the kusto package while the other two (tagged with info) are our own logs.

[image]

Adding this to loglevel in appsettings.json did nothing:

```
"Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data": "Warning"
```

While it worked for other packages.

Comment: _"it's probably more directly writing to console with Console.WriteLine or similar."_ I _**highly**_ doubt that. Please add an example snippet of logoutput as it is now and your config. I am quite confident, you can simply define a category for `Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data` and set it to a higher level filter.

Comment: @Fildor Well it certainly surprised me too but it's the only explanation I can come up with, check my updates.

Comment: Hmmm, looks legit _and odd_. +1 Haven't seen anything like this in my outputs when using Kusto.

Comment: Yea, it's got to be a mistake from the package devs. Iẗ́s not open source so I haven't found a place to report the issue either.

Comment: @Fildor, that's wierd, are you using the same package? Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data (I'm at ver 11.2.1 right now)

Comment: v11.1.0 but that shouldn't change much. I'll have a look into the settings ... maybe I'll find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to (partially) be caused by [Azure Data Explorer Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/controlling-tracing) and adding this snippet got rid of most of the logs:

```
using Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils;

...

    TraceSourceManager.SetTraceVerbosityForAll(TraceVerbosity.Error);
```

Though I still get logs from "Tweaks" when connecting:

[image]

That only happens once so I can live with that for now.